# MySQL : automatically update a column in another table with foreign key, trigger or what?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, database-trigger

I want to do some automatic updates between MySQL many tables, but I wonder how to do it fine. Here is an example :

```
Table `articles` : ID, TEXT, DATE, DELETED

Table `comments` : ID, TEXT, DATE, DELETED

Table `users` : ID, NAME, AGE, DELETED

Table `link` : ID, ARTICLE_ID, COMMENT_ID, USER_ID, DELETED
```

As you guess, the `link` table contains IDs from others.
I have already designed my database like this, to keep tables with the lowest columns as possible.

I know there are lots of questions here about it, but I don't really know what is the best solution. So here is what I want to do :

When a comment is deleted (update `comments` set DELETED=1 where ID=...), I want to update the column `link`.DELETED (=> 1).

When a user is deleted (update `users` set DELETED=1 where ID=...), I want to update the columns `link`.DELETED (=> 1) and `articles`.TEXT (=> NULL).

I know I can use foreign keys between `link`.ARTICLE_ID and `article`.ID for example, and simply delete rows. But I have put limited rights on the user used by my website. I will cron a batch with a more powerful user to delete rows tagged DELETED to cleanup the database.

Is it possible to do that wih FK, or should I use triggers (I don't really know how to use them) or something else ?

I have tried to put FK between DELETED columns but when I update a comments row, all link ones are updated too :/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is probably easiest to do using triggers.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking on the MySQL documentation but the examples are so poor. Do you know some easy how-tos ?

Comment: You should rethink your data model. From your description, it seems an article belongs to (e.g. was written by) exactly one user - so add a column user_id to the article table. (There is probably a similar relation for your comments, e.g written by a user and belonging to one article, but it is not clear from your description). Your premise "to keep tables with the lowest columns as possible" has not much value here, it just makes simple tasks more complicated and, if that was your concern, doesn't even save space (it has just moved to your `link` table).

Comment: In my example, the `link` table is to link a user with his comment on an article. The comment belongs to the user, not the article. It wasn't clear, it's true.

Comment: In my database, I have lots of columns, here is just an simple example easy to understand.

Comment: I want to update more than 1 table when I update a row in 1 table. So I think a trigger would solve it. I'm trying to do one.

Answer (score 0):

I've done what I wanted with the 2 solutions :

- With a trigger : pseudo-delete (update DELETED=1 ...) causes pseudo-delete in my `link` table.
- With a foreign key : true delete (delete from ...) causes true delete in my `link` table.

So, I can pseudo-delete rows from my website, with the basic user.
And I can clean my base with my batch using a user with delete rights.